# How to slice a pandas dataframe by columns using a mix of array of labels and slice of objects?

Tags: python, pandas

Is there a way to slice a pandas dataframe mixing an 'array of labels' with a 'slice of objects'.
I couldn't find an example here [Indexing and Selecting Data](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-label)

A list or array of labels ['a', 'b', 'c']

A slice object with labels 'a':'f'

Here is an example of what I am trying to do without just manually listing them all.

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'Week': [201301, 201301, 201302, 201302, 201303],
'Product': ['coke', 'fanta', 'coke' ,'sprite' ,'pepsi'],
'month1': [12, 1, 3, 12, 11],'month2': [12, 1, 3, 12, 11],
'month3': [12, 1, 3, 12,        11],'month4': [12, 1, 3, 12, 11],
'month5': [12, 1, 3, 12, 11]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

print df
```

Out:

```
   Product    Week  month1  month2  month3  month4  month5
0    coke  201301      12      12      12      12      12
1   fanta  201301       1       1       1       1       1
2    coke  201302       3       3       3       3       3
3  sprite  201302      12      12      12      12      12
4   pepsi  201303      11      11      11      11      11


df= df.loc[:,'Product':'month1']
```

Out:

```
  Product    Week  month1
0    coke  201301      12
1   fanta  201301       1
2    coke  201302       3
3  sprite  201302      12
4   pepsi  201303      11

print df
```

What I want to output is:

```
Product    Week  month1    month4  month5
0    coke  201301      12      12      12   
1   fanta  201301       1       1       1      
2    coke  201302       3       3       3      
3  sprite  201302      12      12      12     
4   pepsi  201303      11      11      11
```

How can i manipulate this line of code:

```
     df= df.loc[:,'Product':'month1']
```

to be something like this(but works):

```
     df= df.loc[:,['Product':'month1'] and ['month4','month5']]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uses some internal methods. Essentially construct the index you want, then use `.loc` to select it out.

```
In [21]: df.loc[:,pd.Index(['Product','Week']) + df.columns[df.columns.slice_indexer('month2','month4')]]
Out[21]: 
  Product    Week  month2  month3  month4
0    coke  201301      12      12      12
1   fanta  201301       1       1       1
2    coke  201302       3       3       3
3  sprite  201302      12      12      12
4   pepsi  201303      11      11      11

[5 rows x 5 columns]
```

Comment: Ok i will play around with that, for now it is saying Index is not defined.

Comment: import pandas as pd; pd.Index is defined their

Comment: Boom. got it, i think the pd. was missing in front of the Index when i tried it. thanks.

Comment: when apply this concept to my larger working file I seem to lose the order of my columns. so month comes before product and month10 comes before month2 etc. why would this happen or rather how can i avoid losing my shape?

Comment: the union (e.g. the '+') sorts, you could do it like this to avoid: ``df.loc[:,['Product','Week']) + df.columns[df.columns.slice_indexer('month2','month4')].tolist()]``

Comment: ok, so that worked in my code when i print the df on the screen(it is in the correct order) but when i export to csv it goes back to the same alphabetical sorting?

Comment: sorry it worked fine to csv export as well. i think i had something stuck in the memory on the first attempt. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can also achieve this by concatenating a few preliminary dataframes:

```
print pd.concat([df.ix[:,"Product":"Week"], df.ix[:,("month1", "month4","month5")]],axis=1)
```

I think this method is easier.